# Multi-select themed WPF tree view like VS project explorer

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview

In my current project I need a WPF (4.0) TreeView control that supports multiple selection and correct Windows theming (regarding selection, focusing and background colour/gradient wrt. node icons...) just like the project explorer in Visual Studio 2010 does it. Now they managed to do it, how can I? Can I maybe use the same control as VS2010 does?

Using Snoop I wasn't able to analyse the GUI. It seems Snoop cannot see the actual contents of the window, just some decoration layers. I don't know about other tools I could use to look into other people's implementation.

So far I've found TreeListView on CodeProject, but it has severe focus issues that make combined keyboard and mouse navigation very cumbersome, and TreeViewEx on CodePlex which also has major focus issues. Both are based on other controls and use adventurous combinations of subcontrols. Both had other bugs which I could partially fix already.

Is there some solid and reliable implementation of this GUI available somewhere?

Comment: Update: I'm working on the focus and other issues with TreeViewEx, so this might become a good solution after all.

Comment: I noticed that the expander button arrows in the VS solution explorer look exactly like those in Windows Explorer, but all of the WPF remakes use a slightly different look. Analysing Visual Studio with Snoop, I noticed that the solution explorer is in fact a hosted native control, so that isn't even WPF after all. So to correct my statement above: they did not manage to do it, at least not here. But there's a WPF solution now anyway (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile I have settled for the [TreeViewEx](http://treeviewex.codeplex.com/) control. After doing numerous modifications and bug fixes, it works best for me. I'm already in contact with the original author to integrate my changes in his code.

**Update:** My forked project is now available on my website. I've renamed it to [MultiSelectTreeView](http://dev.unclassified.de/source/multiselecttreeview) from its most outstanding added feature.